# Run npm script after a package is installed in the project

Tags: node.js, security

What I want is a way to run a script after I have installed a package into my project. The `postinstall` does not work for my case since it runs every time **my** project is installed somewhere else, which is already too late.

Another way would be to use `hooks`

What I want to achieve is to run a security test like `nsp check` after I install a package into my project.

I guess (havent tried it yet) that I can add into `node_modules/.hooks/` a `postinstall` bash script, something like

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
../node_modules/nsp check
```

The problem is that `nsp` package may not have been installed at the moment this script will be executed. So I will have to run the command only if `nsp` is installed, meaning that I will miss the security check for every package that have been installed before `nsp` (in the initial `npm i`), or I will have to install nsp in the `preinstall` phase of my package. These solutions (if they work at all) seem to overcomplicated IMO.

**Is it a way to achieve what I want easier?**

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @LeaHayes unfortunately not.

Comment: thanks for the fast response. If I find a solution to this problem I will post it here; although at this stage it seems doubtful that I'll find a solution :/

Answer (score -4):

I put it in "prepublish".

According to https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts

> prepublish: Run BEFORE the package is published. **(Also run on local npm install without any arguments.)**

I think that "Also run on local npm install" part is what you are looking for.